# How (and why) are random forests able to represent both linear and non linear data

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest, decision-trees

From reading articles I've read that random forests are suited for representing both linear and non linear data quite well, but I can't find an explanation as to how and why it has his flexibility?

Any information to clarify this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decision Trees are able to create both linear and nonlinear boundaries and so are Random Forests.

This is because of how they cluster the data based on **nested "if-else"** statements. These statements draw vertical/horizontal lines between the samples and cluster them in rectangles. Consecutively, rectangles of the same class can be far away from each other (with other class rectangles in between) but still they belong to the same class. This is how nonlinear relations are modeled.

[image]

Comment: Using a nonlinear staircase to fit linear is not ideal though. It needs a much bigger model to have reasonable accuracy, though for many problems it does not really matter

Comment: OP asked to explain "how and why it has this flexibility", not if it's ideal. "Ideal" solutions pretty much depend on the nature of the data.

Comment: Agreed! Just wanted to point out that there are disadvantages also. No silver bullets and all that